# Como ajustar para a variável baseline numa base para Mixed models?

Tags: r

A minha duvida consiste na realização de um mixed models onde me foi pedido para ajustar à variavel baseline

Tenho então a variável peso em 3 momentos (baseline, 4mo e 12mo) em 94 individuos. Para fazer os mixed models tive de reestruturar a base de dados no "long format", ou seja, num formato vertical, ou seja, tenho apenas uma unica coluna para a variavel peso e a variável time (1 2 e 3).

A minha duvida é, como é que consigo ajustar para o peso baseline tendo em conta que ao adicionar a variavel peso incluo a baseline...

Sem covariaveis:
mod1 <- lmer(Weight_1 ~ Group_num*Time + (1|Code), data = data)

Se quiser ajustar para a variavel baseline, como é que faço? Ou seja, o que é que tenho de fazer visto que apenas quero ajustar para o peso do time 1... Terei de adicionar outra base de dados noutro formato?

mod2 <- lmer(Weight_1 ~ Group*Time + **PESO BASELINE** + (1|Code), data=data)

Espero que me consigam ajudar!!

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível. Explicações adicionais sobre o objetivo da análise e o que significam as variáveis `Weight_1`, `Group`, `Time` e `Code` são fundamentais.